# cloud formation unable to receive SUCCESS signal from user-data shell script causing status "ROLLBACK_COMPLETE"

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, ec2-userdata

Below is a shell script which I am using as user-data.sh

The issue is cloud formation stack is not getting a "SUCCESS" signal and therefore it goes to ROLLBACK_COMPLETE status.

```
#!/bin/bash -x
exec > >(tee /var/log/user-data.log|logger -t user-data -s 2>/dev/console) 2>&1

echo "[START] UserData started at $(date +"%d-%m-%Y %H:%M")"

# Install required packages
sudo yum-config-manager --setopt=proxy=http://app-proxy:3128 --save
export no_proxy=".xyz"

# Retrieve service account & GitHub credentials from secret manager
USERNAME=$(aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id smtp-username --query 'SecretString' --output text --region ap-southeast-2)
API_TOKEN=$(aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id smtp-password --query 'SecretString' --output text --region ap-southeast-2)
GITHUB_USERNAME=$(aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id github-username --query 'SecretString' --output text --region ap-southeast-2)
GITHUB_TOKEN=$(aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id github-token --query 'SecretString' --output text --region ap-southeast-2)


# Ensure both credentials input
if [ -z "$USERNAME" ]; then
  echo "Please provide smtp-username."
  exit 1
fi
if [ -z "$API_TOKEN" ]; then
  echo "Please provide smtp-password."
  exit 1
fi
# Ensure both credentials input
if [ -z "$GITHUB_USERNAME" ]; then
  echo "Please provide github-username."
  exit 1
fi
if [ -z "$GITHUB_TOKEN" ]; then
  echo "Please provide github-token."
  exit 1
fi

# Ensure current user is root 
if (( EUID !=0 )); then
  echo "Please run as root!"
  exit
fi

# Check if user albert exits
if grep -q "albert" /etc/passwd;
then
    echo "user albert exists" >> ${LOG_FILE}
else
    useradd albert
fi

# Installing python & pip
echo "Installing python3, pip3"
#sudo yum update -y # For testing purpose so that I don't have to wait for a long time.
sudo yum install python3 python3-pip
sudo yum install git -y

# Open Port 8443 for sample Application
setenforce 0
firewall-cmd --query-port=8443/tcp
firewall-cmd --add-port=8443/tcp --permanent
firewall-cmd --reload
firewall-cmd --query-port=8443/tcp
setenforce 1
#firewall-cmd --query-port=8443/tcp
# Creating directory and grant albert to be owner
echo "Creating directory"
mkdir -p /var/log/pandhu
chown -R albert: albert /var/log/pandhu
chmod 744 /usr/local/lib/
mkdir /app
cd /app/

# Git clone app & kafka repos
git clone https://${GITHUB_USERNAME}:${GITHUB_TOKEN}@github.source.internal.xyz/DigitalT/sample.git
git clone https://${GITHUB_USERNAME}:${GITHUB_TOKEN}@github.source.internal.xyz/DigitalT/kafka.git
chown -R albert: albert /app/

# Retrieve sample application SSL public key & private key
echo "Retrieve app SSL credentials"
cd /app/sample/ssl/
ssl_cert=$(aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id app_test_private_key --query 'SecretString' --output text --region ap-southeast-2 | base64 -d)
ssl_key=$(aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id app_test_public_key --query 'SecretString' --output text --region ap-southeast-2)
echo "${ssl_cert}" > applb.test.confclient.com.crt
echo "${ssl_key}" > applbcerttest.key

# allow SSL credentials able to be read by user albert
chmod 744 /app/sample/ssl/*


# copy SSL file to root directory
cp -apvf /app/sample/ssl/applb.test.confclient.com.crt /etc/pki/tls/certs/applb.test.confclient.com.crt
cp -apvf /app/sample/ssl/applbcerttest.key /etc/pki/tls/private/applbcerttest.key


# Run scripts in user albert environment
su -l albert <<'EOF'

user=albert
if [ "$user" != "albert" ]; then
  echo "user is not albert"
  exit 1
fi
echo "user is albert"


# Install app packages in virtual environment
echo "Creating app environement"
cd /app/sample
python3 -m venv env
echo "Activating app environement ..."
source env/bin/activate
echo "Installing app packages from pypi ..."
pip install -r /app/sample/requirements.txt --no-cache-dir --index-url https://artifactory.internal.xyz/artifactory/api/pypi/org.python.pypi/simple


# Install Kafka packages in virtual environment
echo "Creating Kafka environement"
cd /app/kafka
python3 -m venv env
echo "Activating Kafka environement"
source env/bin/activate
echo "Installing kafka packages"
pip install -r /app/kafka/requirements.txt --no-cache-dir --index-url https://artifactory.internal.xyz/artifactory/api/pypi/org.python.pypi/simple


# Retieve dhondhu credentials from secret manager
echo "Retrieve dhondhu credentials"
cd /app/kafka/dhondhu/etc/
ca_key=$(aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id ca-pem --query 'SecretString' --output text --region ap-southeast-2 | base64 -d)
cybercrime_key=$(aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id cybercrime-key --query 'SecretString' --output text --region ap-southeast-2)
aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id cybercrime-pem --query 'SecretString' --output text --region ap-southeast-2 | base64 -d > cybercrime.pem
dhondhutelemetry_key=$(aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id dhondhutelemetry-key --query 'SecretString' --output text --region ap-southeast-2 | base64 -d)
aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id dhondhutelemetry-pem --query 'SecretString' --output text --region ap-southeast-2 | base64 -d > dhondhutelemetry.pem
splunk_token=$(aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id splunk-api-token --query SecretString --output text --region ap-southeast-2)


# Inject splunk token value to relay.cf
sed -i 's/\!splunk-api-token!/'"${splunk_token}"'/' /app/kafka/dhondhu/relay.cf

# Save dhondhu SSL credentials to file
echo "${ca_key}" > ca.pem
echo "${cybercrime_key}" > cybercrime. Key
echo "${dhondhutelemetry_key}" > dhondhutelemetry.key


echo "Retrieve pandhu credentials from secret manager"
cd /app/kafka/pandhu/etc
trusted_pem=$(aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id pandhu-trusted-pem --query 'SecretString' --output text --region ap-southeast-2 | base64 -d)
aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id kafka-prod-cer --query 'SecretString' --output text --region ap-southeast-2 | base64 -d > kafka_prod.cer
aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id kafka-prod-key --query 'SecretString' --output text --region ap-southeast-2 | base64 -d > kafka_prod.key


# Save pandhu SSL credentials to file
echo "${trusted_pem}" > trusted.pem

# Run server.py
echo "Run app application"
cd /app/sample; source env/bin/activate; if ! (pgrep -a "python" | grep -v "server.py"); then python server.py 8443; fi

# Run kafka scripts
echo "Run kafka and splunk"
source /app/kafka/env/bin/activate; cd /app/kafka/dhondhu; if [ -z $(pgrep -a "python" | grep "relay") ]; then python relay.py; fi
source /app/kafka/env/bin/activate; cd /app/kafka/pandhu; if [ -z $(pgrep -a "python" | grep "ingest2") ]; then python run/ingest2.py; fi

# schedule cron job
echo "Scheduling cron job"
cat /app/sample/albert. Crontab | crontab -

# List cron jobs
crontab -l

TOKEN=$(curl -X PUT "http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token" -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token-ttl-seconds: 21600")
INSTANCE_ID=$(curl -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token: $TOKEN" -v http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)
REGION=$(curl -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token: $TOKEN" -v http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/region)
STACK_NAME=$(aws cloudformation describe-stack-resources \
                     --physical-resource-id $INSTANCE_ID \
                     --query 'StackResources[0].StackName' \
                     --output text)

function signal_cfn() {
    echo "I am in signal_cfn function"
    STACK_STATUS=$(aws cloudformation describe-stacks \
                       --stack-name $STACK_NAME \
                       --query 'Stacks[0].StackStatus' \
                       --output text)
    if [[ "$STACK_STATUS" == "CREATE_IN_PROGRESS" || "$STACK_STATUS" == "UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS" ]]; then
        echo "Instance being created by CloudFormation, signalling $1."
        echo "${1}"
        aws cloudformation signal-resource \
            --stack-name $STACK_NAME \
            --region $REGION \
            --logical-resource-id AutoScalingGroup \
            --unique-id $INSTANCE_ID \
            --status $1
    else
        echo "Not signalling to cfn as instance provisioning wasn't kicked off by CloudFormation."
    fi
}

function wait_for_lb_health_check_to_pass() {
  echo "I am in Load Balancer function"
   local max_attempts=10
   local wait_time_in_seconds=30
   local attempt=0

   _instance_health_status="unhealthy"
   _target_group_arn_parameter_key="LBTargetGroupArn"
   _target_group_arn=$(aws cloudformation describe-stacks \
   --stack-name $STACK_NAME \
   --query "Stacks[0].Parameters[?ParameterKey == '${_target_group_arn_parameter_key}'].ParameterValue" \
   --output text)
   echo "Target group ARN: ${_target_group_arn}"

while [[ $attempt -lt $max_attempts && $_instance_health_status != "healthy" ]]
do
    sleep $wait_time_in_seconds
    attempt=$(( attempt + 1))
    wait_time_in_seconds=$(( wait_time_in_seconds * 2 ))

    _instance_health_status=$(aws elbv2 describe-target-health \
    --target-group-arn $_target_group_arn \
    --targets Id=$INSTANCE_ID,Port=8443 \
    --query "TargetHealthDescriptions[0].TargetHealth.State" \
    --output text)
    echo "Instance health status: ${_instance_health_status}"

    if [[ $_instance_health_status == "healthy" ]]; then
       echo "Instance ${INSTANCE_ID} is healthy now"
       break
    fi
done

if [[ $_instance_health_status != "healthy" ]]; then
    signal_cfn FAILURE
    exit 1;
fi
echo "load balancer function completed"

}

trap "signal_cfn FAILURE" ERR

APP_RUNNING=$(pgrep -u albert -f "server.py")

if [ -z "${APP_RUNNING}" ] ; then
  signal_cfn FAILURE
else
  signal_cfn SUCCESS
fi

echo "Script complete."

wait_for_lb_health_check_to_pass

echo "app ALB Health Checks have passed. Signal SUCCESS to cfn."

echo "[FINISH] UserData finished at $(date +"%d-%m-%Y %H:%M")"

EOF

# TOKEN=$(curl -X PUT "http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token" -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token-ttl-seconds: 21600")
# INSTANCE_ID=$(curl -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token: $TOKEN" -v http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)
# REGION=$(curl -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token: $TOKEN" -v http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/region)
# STACK_NAME=$(aws cloudformation describe-stack-resources \
#                      --physical-resource-id $INSTANCE_ID \
#                      --query 'StackResources[0].StackName' \
#                      --output text)

# function signal_cfn() {
#     echo "I am in signal_cfn function"
#     STACK_STATUS=$(aws cloudformation describe-stacks \
#                        --stack-name $STACK_NAME \
#                        --query 'Stacks[0].StackStatus' \
#                        --output text)
#     if [[ "$STACK_STATUS" == "CREATE_IN_PROGRESS" || "$STACK_STATUS" == "UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS" ]]; then
#         echo "Instance being created by CloudFormation, signalling $1."
#         echo "${1}"
#         aws cloudformation signal-resource \
#             --stack-name $STACK_NAME \
#             --region $REGION \
#             --logical-resource-id AutoScalingGroup \
#             --unique-id $INSTANCE_ID \
#             --status $1
#     else
#         echo "Not signalling to cfn as instance provisioning wasn't kicked off by CloudFormation."
#     fi
# }

# function wait_for_lb_health_check_to_pass() {
#   echo "I am in Load Balancer function"
#    local max_attempts=10
#    local wait_time_in_seconds=30
#    local attempt=0

#    _instance_health_status="unhealthy"
#    _target_group_arn_parameter_key="LBTargetGroupArn"
#    _target_group_arn=$(aws cloudformation describe-stacks \
#    --stack-name $STACK_NAME \
#    --query "Stacks[0].Parameters[?ParameterKey == '${_target_group_arn_parameter_key}'].ParameterValue" \
#    --output text)
#    echo "Target group ARN: ${_target_group_arn}"

# while [[ $attempt -lt $max_attempts && $_instance_health_status != "healthy" ]]
# do
#     sleep $wait_time_in_seconds
#     attempt=$(( attempt + 1))
#     wait_time_in_seconds=$(( wait_time_in_seconds * 2 ))

#     _instance_health_status=$(aws elbv2 describe-target-health \
#     --target-group-arn $_target_group_arn \
#     --targets Id=$INSTANCE_ID,Port=8443 \
#     --query "TargetHealthDescriptions[0].TargetHealth.State" \
#     --output text)
#     echo "Instance health status: ${_instance_health_status}"

#     if [[ $_instance_health_status == "healthy" ]]; then
#        echo "Instance ${INSTANCE_ID} is healthy now"
#        break
#     fi
# done

# if [[ $_instance_health_status != "healthy" ]]; then
#     signal_cfn FAILURE
#     exit 1;
# fi
# echo "load balancer function completed"

# }

# trap "signal_cfn FAILURE" ERR

# APP_RUNNING=$(pgrep -u albert -f "server.py")

# if [ -z "${APP_RUNNING}" ] ; then
#   signal_cfn FAILURE
# else
#   signal_cfn SUCCESS
# fi

# echo "Script complete."

# wait_for_lb_health_check_to_pass

# echo "app ALB Health Checks have passed. Signal SUCCESS to cfn."

# echo "[FINISH] UserData finished at $(date +"%d-%m-%Y %H:%M")"
```

Error Message:

```
The following resource(s) failed to create: [AutoScalingGroup]. Rollback requested by user.
Failed to receive 1 resource signal(s) for the current batch. Each resource signal timeout is counted as a FAILURE.
Received 0 SUCCESS signal(s) out of 1. Unable to satisfy 100% MinSuccessfulInstancesPercent requirement
```

I did try to incorporate the code  from TOKEN  till echo "[FINISH]..." AFTER EOF, what does happen is that I go to the VM and execute the cfn signal bit and the stack is created.

Unfortunately that will not work as again one has to do SSH and then execute last cfn_signal bit manually.

I am pretty confused what is the issue that is not sending SUCCESS signal back to CloudFormation API.

Comment: Is the instance being launched in a Public Subnet or a Private subnet? The `cfn-signal` command needs to send the response to an endpoint on the Internet, so it wither need to be in a Public subnet or it must be able to send the message via a NAT Gateway.

Comment: The private subnet is using proxy settings to send the message back to the CloudFormation API.
When I ssh on the server and run the section for cfn_signal it works fine so I think the problem might be in then  shell script but I am not entirely sure.

Comment: Look in `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log` to obtain a log of the User Data script. You have some good `echo` statements, so it should be possible to find where the script is failing. Configure the CloudFormation stack to **Preserve successfully provisioned resources** to prevent rollback so that you can access the EC2 instance after failure.

Comment: Thank you @JohnRotenstein Issue is the python application running in the foreground. I am trying to figure out how to run in the background.

Comment: You should be able to use `&` to run something in the background (eg `python relay.py &`).

Comment: Spot on! I tried the nohup python & and got it working :) Thanks John!